# How To Prove it: 7.1.6

Tags: elementary-set-theory

**Definition 7.1.1.** Suppose $A$ and $B$ are sets. We’ll say that $A$ is *equinumerous* with $B$ if there is a function $f : A → B$ that is *one-to-one* and *onto*. We’ll write $A ∼ B$ to indicate that $A$ is *equinumerous* with $B$. For each natural number $n$, let $I_{n}$ = { $i ∈ Z^+ | i ≤ n$ }. A set $A$ is called finite if there is a natural number $n$ such that $I_{n} ∼ A$. Otherwise, A is infinite.

**Question 7.1.6:** Prove that for all natural numbers $n$ and $m$, if $I_{n}$ ∼ $I_{m} $ then $n$ = $m$. (Hint: Use induction on n.)

**My Attempt:** Suppose $I_{n}$ ∼ $I_{m}$ where $ n \in \Bbb N$, $m \in \Bbb N $ are both arbitrary, then we can choose a function $f : I_{n} → I_{m}$ that is *one-to-one* and *onto*. Since $f$ is *one-to-one* there must the same number of elements in $I_{m}$ as in $I_{n}$ or we can say $m = n$. Then we can conclude that if $I_{n}$ ∼ $I_{m}$ then $n = m$.

I am assuming that its wrong because the book suggests to used induction but I can't see why it is so. What am I missing?

Also is it ok to write $n, m \in \Bbb N $ instead of $ n \in \Bbb N$, $m \in \Bbb N $.

Comment: Perhaps the phrase "the same number of elements" is somewhat ambiguous on general sets, i.e. the number of even numbers and the number of whole numbers are all the same, even though one can find all even numbers inside the whole numbers... This is ok for finite sets, but perhaps that's the issue your book wants to avoid...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One problem with your proof is in the line:

> Since $f$ is one-to-one there must be the same number of elements in
>   $I_m$ as in $I_n$.

This is not a true fact! For instance, I can define a function $f:\{1\}\rightarrow\{1, 2\}$ with $f(1)=1$. It is 1-1, but the sets are not equinumerous. Of course, my $f$ is not onto; this is why you need both. Incidentally, 1-1 is sometimes called "injective" and onto is sometimes called "surjective"; a function that is both is called "bijective".

Perhaps a larger problem is that you haven't actually used the properties of $f$. You can't just *say* "because $f$ is bijective, $m=n$", because *that's what you need to prove*. So suppose you have $I_n\sim I_m \Rightarrow n = m$, and a bijection between them. Now consider $I_{n+1}$ and $I_{m+1}$. Can you find a bijection between them based on the one you had for $I_n$ and $I_m$? That's the induction.

Lastly, yes, it's ok to say $\forall m,n \in \Bbb{N}$. Actually it's not ok to say, $\{\forall i \in Z^+ \mid i \leq n\}$, as you did. The $\forall$ is extraneous. Correct would be: $\{ i \in \Bbb{Z}^+ \mid i \leq n \}$, pronounced "the set of $i$ in $\Bbb{Z}^+$ such that $i \leq n$".

Comment: I meant to write that since it is 1-1 and onto, it implies that the no of elements in the range and domain of f be equal and since the no of elements in the domain is n and in the range is m, n = m.

Comment: Nevermind, I understand it now